# Автоформатирование и emmet для Stylus

Tags: css, вёрстка, препроцессор, stylus, frontend

Проблема такая - пишу на стилусе и часто вставляю код из инструмента для разработчиков в браузере. Выходит грязно, потому что в stylus нет двоеточия и точки с запятой по умолчанию. Но работает) Есть что-то типа CSScomb, только для стилуса?
И еще похожая проблема - когда использую emmet, ну например пишу mt10 + tab - тоже выставляется двоеточие, т.е. margin-top: 10px
Как это можно настроить? Использую phpstorm, если что.

Comment: В Sublime Text решаются данные проблемы. // **1.** Если использовать пакет [**CSS to Stylus Converter**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20To%20SASS%20And%20Stylus%20Converter), CSS, который Вы вставляете, как всегда (обычно `Ctrl+V`), будет автоматически преобразован в Stylus. // **2.** Проверил в Sublime Text Ваш пример — Emmet двоеточие не выставляет. Спасибо.